# Replace the reference to the DOM object

Tags: javascript, dom, reference

I want to write a Javascript function that would replace one DOM element by another one. Also I need the reference to the old element to be pointing to the new element after replacement.

I wrote the following function for this purpose:

```
var replaceDomElement = function (el1, el2) {
    var parent = el1.parentNode;
    if (!parent) return false;

    parent.replaceChild(el2, el1);

    el1 = el2;
    return true;
}
```

But this doesn't work in the way I want.
DOM element is properly replaced.

But the statement `el1 = el2` doesn't work.
After execution of this function el1 is still pointing to the old element, that has no parent now.

What is the correct way of changing the references to the DOM object inside a function?

Comment: What code uses replaceDomElement?  in your current code, el1 and el2 only exist within the function scope and changing their values in the function would not effect references to them in other locations in your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code works as you want:

```
var replaceDomElement = function (el1, el2) {
    var parent = el1.parentNode;
    if (!parent) return false;

    parent.replaceChild(el2, el1);

    return el2;
}

var element1 = document.getElementById("el1");
var element2 = document.getElementById("el2");
element1 = replaceDomElement(element1, element2);
alert(element1 === element2);
```

I.e. at the end element1 is equal to element2. The difference is that you return el2. Here is a codepen showing the example http://codepen.io/krasimir/pen/LcyFe

Comment: And what if I call `element1 = replaceDomElement(element1, element2);` from inside of another function that takes `element1` as an argument?

Comment: You could have element1 as a global var and not pass it into a function. When you pass the argument to the function it is passed by value no by ref meaning it creates a copy of the object inside the function.

Comment: @BartoNaz it will have the same effect. I mean it will work as you expect. element1 will be equal to element2. If you don't want to overwrite the passed argument, just change the name of the variables.

Comment: OK, I'll think what to do with this. I read somewhere that Objects in Javascript are passed to function by reference. But it seems not to be the case. Thanks for help...